# Problem with launching Discord (Fedora 35)

Tags: discord, fedora

I can't run Discord on fedora 35
What could be the cause of this?

```
[Modules] Module download path: /home/devfedora/.config/discord/0.0.16/modules/pending
[21162:1122/064313.174662:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.

Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id: 15fc2f96-e5c8-4c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue for me was that Discord needed sudo privileges in order to run. I don't want to run it with elevated privileges every time, so I uninstalled it via DNF, and installed it via FlatPak

1. Open Discover, and install "Sideload"
2. Click on install from [flathub](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/com.discordapp.Discord), and open it in Sideload. Sideload will then install it and provide updates in the Discover app.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works after installation by flatpak

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this issue by running discord with `--no-sandbox` flag.
If you open Discord via application launcher then you can edit the Discord.desktop file and add `--no-sandbox` to the end of the Exec line.